# Need help to make this layout more readable

Tags: navigation, menu, multi-column

I am having trouble figuring out what is the best way to do this layout?
Any suggestion on how to improve the layout would be much appreciated.
Thank you in advance.
[image: Footer layout]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find the answer at the bottom of this page. You could see elements grouped in sections.
[image]

Placing headers on one horizontal level makes it easier to scan through them.

Don't use padding for elements, showing them under headers. The difference of the headers text formatting shows relation strong enough, so using padding as second sign is excessive and not so elegant from visual point.

`View All Skin Notion` link has weak contrast and doesn't look like link.